# Trouble with multiple choice quiz

Tags: javascript

Having trouble with the code below. When user clicks a button, I want to set the value of clickedAnswer accordingly. Then I can validate the button clicked against the answer later on. Currently, I'm logging a 4 every time.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
let clickedAnswer = 1;
           
function setClickedAnswer(button) {
    if (button.id === "option1") {
        clickedAnswer = 1;
    } else if (button.id === "option2") {
        clickedAnswer = 2;
    } else if (button.id === "option3") {
        clickedAnswer = 3;
    } else {
        clickedAnswer = 4;
    }
    validateAnswer();
    console.log(clickedAnswer);
}

answer1.addEventListener("click", setClickedAnswer);
answer2.addEventListener("click", setClickedAnswer);
answer3.addEventListener("click", setClickedAnswer);
answer4.addEventListener("click", setClickedAnswer);
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant code in the question?  When editing the question, you can even make a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to demonstrate.

Comment: What is `button.id`'s value?

Answer (score 1):

The function is expecting the button itself to be passed:

```
function setClickedAnswer(button) {
```

However, no such button is passed:

```
answer1.addEventListener("click", setClickedAnswer);
```

What *is* sent to an event handler by default is [the event object itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), which has a `target` property referring to the element invoking the event.  So you can do this:

```
if (button.target.id === "option1") {
```

(repeat for the other conditions, of course)

---

Alternatively, if you prefer the function to expect a button element, you can wrap a function around your event handler invokation and pass the element there:

```
answer1.addEventListener("click", () => setClickedAnswer(answer1));
```

or:

```
answer1.addEventListener("click", function () { setClickedAnswer(answer1); });
```

Comment: @ChaseJohnston https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work